# nice html reports for pyunit

Tags: python, html, python-unittest

Do you know a tool for creating nice html reports for pyunit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest the following:

1. Run your tests using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/)
2. Create a nose plugin that outputs results as HTML. The nose example code has a simple HTML output plugin (https://raw.github.com/nose-devs/nose/master/examples/html_plugin/htmlplug.py). You can probably use that, at least as a starting point.

Nose plug-in documentation: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Another option:

- Nose can output test results as NUnit-compatible XML: `nosetests --with-xunit`. This will produce a `nostests.xml` file in the current directory.
- There are solutions to convert this XML to HTML:

  - For instance, Hudson/Jenkins displays XML test results as HTML in the browser.
  - [How to convert NUnit output into an HTML report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996219/how-to-convert-nunit-output-into-an-html-report)
  - http://www.google.com/search?&q=nunit+xml+to+html

Answer (score 1):

there has a simple HTMLTestRunner developed for pyunit, here is [link](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html)

The shortage of it is there are no output in console, because sys.stdout and sys.stderr was captured by HTMLTestRunner.  Except above, others works fine to me.