# How to produce HTML unit test output in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm looking for any way to display the results of Python unit tests in an HTML summary. There are tools like this for Java and Ruby... haven't yet located any tools that seem to do this for Python. Are there any out there?

**JUnit HTML output:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails03118/UnitTestReport.jpg))</sub>

**Ruby RSpec output:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [natontesting.com](http://www.natontesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/rspec_output.gif))</sub>

Comment: There is a similar question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767377/nice-html-reports-for-pyunit

Comment: yeah... that answer just says "write your own" :P

Comment: Yes, there is something like that written, it's at http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html. Here is the sample output: http://tungwaiyip.info/software/sample_test_report.html

Comment: Questions asking for "libraries, tools, or other offsite resources" are explicitly off topic, because the answers tend to grow stale very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There are now ways to do it using Python. Using `pytest`, for example:

```sh
pip install pytest pytest-html
```

And then:

```sh
pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html
```

[image: Results in HTML of pytest]