# Display python unittest results in nice, tabular form

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest, test-reporting

I am writing a Pythonic tool which validates the correctness of a certain system. Each validation is written as a Python [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), and the report looks like:

```
test_exclude_list_not_empty (__main__.TestRepoLists)
Assert the the exclude list is not empty ... ok
test_include_list_not_empty (__main__.TestRepoLists)
Assert the the include list is not empty ... ok
test_repo_list_not_empty (__main__.TestRepoLists)
Assert the the repo list is not empty ... ok
```

In my opinion, this format is hard to read, especially for non-Pythonists. Is there any report generator that can generate a report in a nice, tabular form, e.g.:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Test                                                           |  Status   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Assert the the exclude list is not empty                       |  OK       |
| Assert the the include list is not empty                       |  OK       |
| Assert the the repo list is not empty                          |  OK       |
| All the items in the include list should be in the repo list   |  OK       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Clarification** The test suite runs on a remote terminal, so I prefer command line reporting tools.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are asking, but there are several options for having a readable test output there:

- [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) generates easy to use HTML test reports in a tabular form. [Here](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/sample_test_report.html)'s a sample report.
- [nose-html-output](https://github.com/cboylan/nose-html-output) plugin for [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test runner
- [unittest-xml-reporting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-xml-reporting) - PyUnit-based test runner with JUnit like XML reporting
- nose with `--with-xunit` option will produce junit xml style reports that are easy to read and convert

Also see:

- [How to produce html unit test output in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758354/how-to-produce-html-unit-test-output-in-python)
- [Python Unittest Reporting in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138311/python-unittest-reporting-in-html)
- [unittest colored output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203633/unittest-colored-output) (coloring the output can make results readable too)

If you want to see test results in a tabular form in the console anyway, I think that a good idea would be to write your [own nose plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html) or test runner based on `unittest.TestProgram` as it was done in [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner_0_8_2/HTMLTestRunner.py).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, sure, you can install any of these xml/html producing tools on the server-side and use on a remote terminal shell. But, in this case you'll need to download reports first to see them in the browser, of course. Or, alternatively, you can use a text-based web browser like [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) to see reports right in the console.

Comment: That would overcomplicate the matters. I think that a simple tabulation within the shell will do.

Comment: Agreed, then consider going with custom runner or a nose plugin. I don't think there is anything written out there specifically for this particular problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to create a test class of my own. Just wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You know that an answer is not worthy to be read nor posted if it starts with "This is not exactly what you are asking"

Comment: @User9123 hey, it was worth a worthy comment. Achievement unlocked.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add my information as a comment into alecxe's answer, but I do not have enough reputation for that.

In case of someone still looking for an answer, I forked HTMLTestRunner into a simple TestRunner, which has a tabular, colored, terminal-friendly output.
This is a sample of its output:

[image: Example]

The source code is at https://gist.github.com/viniciusd/73e6eccd39dea5e714b1464e3c47e067

I shall rewrite it from scratch soon but keeping the output format.

Comment: The source code link no longer works. Do you have an updated link to share?

Comment: Ok, I am hosting it on Gist while I do not set a nice repository on Github

Comment: with python 2, it is not able to discover tests.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Twisted's Trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial).

By default, it uses the `TreeReporter` test runner, which looks like:

[image: Trial's reporting]

It has the following:

- It's a command line report, just run:

  `trial test_name.py`
- Colored output: red for failure, green for success
- The report uses a tree like structure. It displays the tests under the TestCases they belong, allowing you to quickly traverse the results to find a specific test. (Although it provides a couple of more [reports](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.trial.reporter.html)).
- It also includes a test library, derived from Python's `unittest.TestCase`. You can use this library by subclassing  `twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase`. This provides a few more [assertion methods](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase.html).
- It includes the option to generate statement coverage for your tests.