# How to convert NUnit output into an HTML report

Tags: html, formatting, nunit

Does anyone have any suggestions for a good tool, xslt or other that can produce an HTML report from the XML output of NUnit?

We're currently using NUnit 2.5.5 to run a number of tests on our code base. The dev team are happy seeing the output in the GUI and console runners and the report shown on our Hudson server.

The Hudson generated report needs a user to click links to drill down to some of the details.  I would like to produce a single document report suitable for showing to management and/or the client.

Thus far, the only tool I've found is http://nunit2report.sourceforge.net/ which hasn't been updated sine 2003, is based on an old version of NUnit (I think the report format might have changed significantly?) and is a nant task (we don't use nant).

Before I spend too long trying to doctor nunit2reports xslt's to suit the recent NUnit's output, can anyone point be to a more suitable tool?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you use NUnit 3+ version, please see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219661/are-there-any-ways-to-create-html-report-for-nunit3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found two other tools.

- [nunit-summary](https://launchpad.net/nunit-summary)
- [nunit-results](https://github.com/CharliePoole/nunit-results)

Both are available on Lauchpad, linked to from the very basic product pages linked above.

Unfortunately, neither of these tools provided the required level of detail for our installation - so I ended up doctoring the xslt's that came with [nunit2report](http://nunit2report.sourceforge.net/) to suit out needs.

Comment: Any chance you could share the xslt you came up with :)

Comment: @solrev - Its on an non-internet-connected system at another site.  I'll see if I can take a copy to share when I'm next there...

Comment: These are all 404s now

Comment: @Chris S I've updated the links. Hopefully that's more useful - although it doesn't look like the projects have been touched in years...

Answer (score 23):

ReportUnit is not maintained and is being replaced by [extentreports-dotnet-cli](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli).

---

You can also try ReportUnit, which also supports Gallio, xUnit, TestNG and MSTest:  http://reportunit.relevantcodes.com

This is a simple exe file that will convert your xml report into an HTML dashboards (samples):

- Folder-level dashboard:  http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ReportUnit/Index.html
- File-level:  http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ReportUnit/NUnit-TestResult.html

Usage:

```
reportunit "path-to-folder" // folder-level report
reportunit "path-to-folder" "output-folder" // folder-level report
reportunit "Result.xml" "generated.html" // file-level report
```

More info here:  http://reportunit.relevantcodes.com

Comment: It's nice but take note that ReportUnit uses Google Vizualization APIs among other online resources. The html file is not pretty offline.

Comment: website appears to be down and/or broken links

Comment: yeah, site is broken, but you can do google search for that site, select "cached" and from there have access to their git repo https://github.com/reportunit/reportunit  actually it works even with nunit3-console xml result.

Comment: 2017 comment, `ReportUnit 1.2.1` still works with our `TestResult.xml` from `NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.4.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe`

But it is not under active development. The github repo does not have tag on v1.2.1 release for me to make some change.

The latest v1.5.0 HTML output does not work as expected (it shows result, but does not response to click on buttons, checkboxes, ...)

Comment: ReportUnit is no longer supported, is replaced by https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli which is part of the Extent Framework. As of this comment, the cli is in alpha and tested to work with NUnit 2.x and 3.x. it will become available to Nuget soon.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, but it's the top result in Google on the subject and thought it deserved a mention.. Where I work had the exact same issue so we developed a little app that will parse an XML results file and output a nice looking self-contained HTML page based on bootstrap 3. Code and binaries are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/JatechUK/NUnit-HTML-Report-Generator). It's responsive as well as we email the reports to mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Nice report it generates too.

Comment: Could you provide step by step detail on how to use this?

Comment: There should be enough detail in the readme to explain how to use the project. Check the standard usage section for an example of how it works: https://github.com/JatechUK/NUnit-HTML-Report-Generator#standard-usage

Comment: Nice work - thank you. There's a fork for NUnit V3 at https://github.com/SongArc/NUnit-HTML-Report-Generator ...but you should check the network graph of the original to see if this isthe latest and greatest.

Comment: Looks like there is no active work being done on it in a while (no Nunit3 support), and a lot of unmerged forks.

Answer (score 6):

This looks decent, works with NUnit3, is free and actively maintained as of Sept 2017:
https://ghpreporter.github.io/

Github:
https://github.com/GHPReporter/Ghpr.Core

Sample Report:
http://ghpreporter.github.io/report/?currentTab=runs-stats

Comment: Is there an idiot guide on how to install and use it ?

Comment: @Epligam Just click 'Some Links' on their github page.  Here's the steps to get it working for NUnit: https://github.com/GHPReporter/Ghpr.NUnit

Answer (score 3):

There's also an 'nunit2report' task in NAntContrib (which was recently updated with the NAnt 0.91 release).

[NAntContrib NUnit2Report Task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/nunit2report.html)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is the most searchable NUnit HTML answer.
So for NUnit 3 Allure would be the best option

[image: Allure]

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2 - global repo

https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit - for NUnit