# Generating html from Nunit xml test results

Tags: nunit

I am generating the xml output of nunit tests using:

```
 nunit-console /xml:console-test.xml nunit.tests.dll
```

How can I create a table formatted report using the xml. Is there any tool for that?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996219/how-to-convert-nunit-output-into-an-html-report

Answer (score 0):

You can bind xml to a datagrid to display it as a table with a handful of lines of C#.

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/binding-raw-xml-to-a-datagrid-control-in-asp-net/

Something like:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("console-test.xml"),XmlReadMode.InferSchema); 
this.DataGrid1.DataSource = ds; 
this.DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Problem with this is (at least for NUnit 2.5.5) that the structure of the XML file is not well formed, and throws the following error at runtime: 'The table (test-suite) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations.'

Answer (score 0):

Or use an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) transformer to generate the HTML from the xml.