# NUnit: Can I get HTML report instead of XML?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

NUnit 3.0.

I use such code in my application for test running:

```
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string[] nunitArgs = new List<string>
 {
   // for details of options see  http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=nunitliteOptions&r=3.0
   "--verbose",
   "--work=" + directoryName // save TestResults.xml to the build folder
 }.ToArray();

new NUnitLite.Runner.TextUI().Execute(nunitArgs);
```

I get output report in the `XML` format, but I need `HTML`. [Here](http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=nunitliteOptions&r=3.0) I see - only `XML` can be used as output report format. Perhaps I incorrect understood the documentation? I can write XSLT for this XML, but I will do it only if I be sure to get HTML result impossible for NUnit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert NUnit output into an HTML report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996219/how-to-convert-nunit-output-into-an-html-report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works: http://relevantcodes.com/nunit-orange-nunit-html-report-generator/
It successfully generated HTML report from the XML.

Answer (score 3):

Bush

[NUnitOrange](http://relevantcodes.com/nunit-orange-nunit-html-report-generator/) seems to be working with the latest version of XML (NUnit 3.0).  Sorry for posting an answer, I am unable to leave a comment.  Thanks to you and Michal for sharing the links.

This comment by the dev also:  http://relevantcodes.com/nunit-orange-nunit-html-report-generator/#comment-185530.  Seems to be in beta but it works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure HTML output is not natively supported by NUnit. Also, you will probably don't have to implement your XSLT from scratch, [there appear to be tools for that purpose already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2996219/3242721).

Comment: @Bush have you looked at the second answer as well? It links the [GitHub project](https://github.com/JatechUK/NUnit-HTML-Report-Generator), the answer is only 6 months old so I believe project should be in a good shape.

Comment: I compiled that solution and tryed to use: it generate an exception and breaking own process.

Comment: Maybe NUnitLite creates XML with other structure.

Comment: @Bush Will try later and let you know of my results.

Comment: Thank you. If you want - I can send to you my XML. This is report of working four tests.