# Are there any ways to create HTML report for NUnit3?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I saw several solutions for NUnit 2.x version. For example, I can create XSLT, or use Allure Reporter.

But how can I do it for **NUnit 3.x** version (without writing my own XSLT for NUnit XML results)?

Allure does not work with NUnit3.

Comment: Is there any official solution in the mean time? The test reports are barely human readable, so an integrated html output would be awesome...

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using [GHPReporter](https://github.com/GHPReporter).
You can create reports for NUnit 3, SpecFlow and MSTest.

No additional attributes required for NUnit 3. Just set up addin (see short instruction in README file: https://github.com/GHPReporter/Ghpr.NUnit) and run your tests with NUnit3 Console.

View your report locally in Firefox:

- Go to `about:config`
- Find `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` parameter
- Set it to `false`

View your report locally in Chrome:

- Close your Chrome (all instances)
- Launch it with `--allow-file-access-from-files` option:
  eg `C:\PATH TO\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Also see demo report [here](https://ghpreporter.github.io/)

**EDITED**

[NUnitGo](https://github.com/elv1s42/NUnitGo) is no longer maintained.

Comment: GHPReporter runs on an old .NET version, it cannot be used with v4.6. I can't downgrade my entire solution just to support reporting.

Comment: @metabuddy, now it supports multiple framework versions: `netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp2.2;netcoreapp3.0;net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472`